# Raspberry pi controlled drone: using raspberry pi as a receiver

Tags: quadcopters, flight-controller, receiver, raspberry-pi

I build a drone very similar to the Rotor Riot Cinewhoop, I want to use a Raspberry Pi zero to make the drone fly autonomously.
I think that the best idea is to use the Raspberry Pi as a receiver, and to send simple commands: throttle, roll, pitch, yaw, to the flight controller.
I am not sure what connection is the best: serial, sbus? I have the T-motor MINI F7 (HD +OSD +VTX SWITCH).
I know that I could use another flight controller (Pixhawk, or other autopilot) but I don't have money nor time to buy a new one.
Thanks!!!

Comment: I think using this library could be a solution:
https://github.com/1arthur1/PiSBUS

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a serial communication protocol such as SBUS would be easiest.

There are a number of open source projects that explain how to use it, such as: https://github.com/bolderflight/sbus/blob/main/README.md

Comment: Thanks, noob question: is that particular one compatible with raspberry pi, is it the same as cmake?

Comment: Also: can this be done using python? Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you could probably use python, as the PI is powerful enough to run it. I don't know much about it though.